# Is there a way to control the speed at which Curl reports progress?

Tags: bash, curl, cygwin

I'm using Curl in Cygwin to automate a daily download.  I want to keep progress in a log but Curl is just a little too noisy for my taste. I tried `man curl` and Google, but didn't find anything.

Can I slow down the frequency at which Curl reports progress?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is straight ripped off from the manual page, section `PROGRESS METER`:

> ```
>    If you prefer a progress "bar" instead of the regular meter, -# is your
>    friend.
> ```

Example:

```
delicious:~ ajanssen$ curl -# http://www.heise.de > bla
######################################################################## 100,0%
```

Vs:

```
delicious:~ ajanssen$ curl http://www.heise.de > bla
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   98k    0   98k    0     0   164k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  169k
```

Comment: Thanks. I did see that but not quite what I was looking for